# Fill page with element to print up to margins

Tags: html, css, printing, cross-browser

I am trying to fill a page to be printed with a `<div>` set to `100vh` and `100vw` ([MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Sizing_items_in_CSS#Viewport_units) on relative viewport height and width).

I'd expect the page (and the viewport) to be filled to the margins with a gray rectangle with red border.

Tested with

- Chrome (85.0.4183.102)
- Edge (44.18362.449.0)
- Firefox (80.0.1)

Chrome:

- screen: OK
- print preview: OK
- print (PDF): OK

Edge:

- screen: no bottom border
- print preview: OK
- print: OK

Firefox:

- screen: no bottom border
- print preview: one page with red rectangle cutoff on the right, does not fill page (approx. 3/4)
- print (to PDF printer): two pages, cutoff on right

Enabling "shrink to fit" causes an empty page in print preview, and the print is a rectangle about 2/3 width and height.
Printing to A4 with zero margins and 100%, the preview looks like FF is confusing landscape with portrait and cuts off at the right, but "printing" almost gets it right, there's only a slight gap between the red line and the bottom edge of the page.

It seems the margins are broken in Firefox then https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1329527 is probably related.

But before I open another bug report, could someone confirm that my approach to CSS is correct? And is there another method / workaround to get this to work in all current browsers?

```css
html,
body,
#test {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#test {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

I'm actually testing with this file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset=UTF-8>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            html, body, #test{ 
                margin:0; 
                padding:0;
            }
            #test{
                box-sizing: border-box;
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100vw;
                border: 1px solid red;
                background: gray;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lots of bug reports in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?product=Core&component=Printing%3A%20Output&list_id=15405429 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?product=Core&component=Print%20Preview&list_id=15405432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with Firefox. Version 81, scheduled for release on 2020-09-22, has better support for this scenario.